# Firewall rules for ssh, ftp and webapps

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall, ftp

I'm running a small cluster with Centos 7 and want the following rules for firewall.

- Have ssh access from anywhere (i'm going to further configure that from /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
- Have ftp access to an ftp server
- Have access to a webapp running at :7180
- Have full access from some servers
- Log all events
- Prevent DDoS

I have written the following script but don't know if it's the optimal way. Any suggestions?

> `#! /bin/bash
>
> IPTABLES=/usr/sbin/iptables
>   MY_NET=server1.sample.com,server2.sample.com,server3.sample.com
>   MY_IP=123.456.789.101
>   FTP=ftp.sample.com
>
> $IPTABLES -F
>
> $IPTABLES -I INPUT 1 -j LOG
>   $IPTABLES -I OUTPUT 1 -j LOG
>
> $IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
>   $IPTABLES -P OUTPUT DROP
>
> $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s $MY_NET,$MY_IP -j ACCEPT $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $MY_NET,$MY_IP -j ACCEPT
>
> $FTP -m multiport --dports 20,21 -j ACCEPT $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $FTP -m multiport --dports 20,21 -j ACCEPT
>
> $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,7180 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>   $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,7180 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
>
> $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22,8080,7180 -m limit --limit
>   25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Why don't you just use firewalld?

Answer (score 1):

- The best solution for firewall is forbid all and then make a holes.
- Make one chain for protocol
- Make rules structured not linear, it help to be faster in big load.
- For LOG use with limit too, beware full log disk partition.

Some example which not cover your example, but show way howto

```
$IPTABLES -n ftp
$IPTABLES -n ssh
$IPTABLES -n webapp
$IPTABLES -n icmp
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP

#first log (i think better log only good or only bad)
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -m limit --limit 25/minute -j LOG
#decide to which chain goto...
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --port 7180 -j webapp
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p icmp -j icmp
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ssh

#fill chain specific for protocol (port was matched before)
$IPTABLES -A webapp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A icmp -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
#ssh accept packet to all destionation.. it is quicker then state comparsion
$IPTABLES -A ssh -j ACCEPT 

#for output make other chain than input
$IPTABLES -N ssh_out
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A ssh_out -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ssh_out
$IPTABLES -A ssh_out -j DROP #or make drop policy on output...
```

And so one...